# Mlflow "load_model" goes in deadlock

Tags: python, paramiko, mlflow

Trying to load a model from past run in mlflow, in jupyterlab, never finishes. After waiting for hours, interrupting the run throws the below state.

[image]

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [21], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 logged_model = 'runs:/7f6932baef144fa69847ba11ef66f8e6/model/'
----> 2 loaded_model = mlflow.tensorflow.load_model(logged_model)

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tensorflow/__init__.py:397, in load_model(model_uri, dst_path)
    360 def load_model(model_uri, dst_path=None):
    361     """
    362     Load an MLflow model that contains the TensorFlow flavor from the specified path.
    363 
   (...)
    395                                 for _, output_signature in signature_definition.outputs.items()]
    396     """
--> 397     local_model_path = _download_artifact_from_uri(artifact_uri=model_uri, output_path=dst_path)
    398     flavor_conf = _get_flavor_configuration(local_model_path, FLAVOR_NAME)
    399     _add_code_from_conf_to_system_path(local_model_path, flavor_conf)

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/artifact_utils.py:95, in _download_artifact_from_uri(artifact_uri, output_path)
     92     parsed_uri = parsed_uri._replace(path=posixpath.dirname(parsed_uri.path))
     93     root_uri = prefix + urllib.parse.urlunparse(parsed_uri)
---> 95 return get_artifact_repository(artifact_uri=root_uri).download_artifacts(
     96     artifact_path=artifact_path, dst_path=output_path
     97 )

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/runs_artifact_repo.py:125, in RunsArtifactRepository.download_artifacts(self, artifact_path, dst_path)
    110 def download_artifacts(self, artifact_path, dst_path=None):
    111     """
    112     Download an artifact file or directory to a local directory if applicable, and return a
    113     local path for it.
   (...)
    123     :return: Absolute path of the local filesystem location containing the desired artifacts.
    124     """
--> 125     return self.repo.download_artifacts(artifact_path, dst_path)

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py:242, in ArtifactRepository.download_artifacts(self, artifact_path, dst_path)
    240 # Check if the artifacts points to a directory
    241 if self._is_directory(artifact_path):
--> 242     dst_local_path, inflight_downloads = async_download_artifact_dir(
    243         src_artifact_dir_path=artifact_path, dst_local_dir_path=dst_path
    244     )
    245 else:
    246     inflight_downloads = async_download_artifact(
    247         src_artifact_path=artifact_path, dst_local_dir_path=dst_path
    248     )

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py:208, in ArtifactRepository.download_artifacts.<locals>.async_download_artifact_dir(src_artifact_dir_path, dst_local_dir_path)
    206 for file_info in dir_content:
    207     if file_info.is_dir:
--> 208         inflight_downloads += async_download_artifact_dir(
    209             src_artifact_dir_path=file_info.path,
    210             dst_local_dir_path=dst_local_dir_path,
    211         )[2]
    212     else:
    213         inflight_downloads += async_download_artifact(
    214             src_artifact_path=file_info.path,
    215             dst_local_dir_path=dst_local_dir_path,
    216         )

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py:199, in ArtifactRepository.download_artifacts.<locals>.async_download_artifact_dir(src_artifact_dir_path, dst_local_dir_path)
    195 local_dir = os.path.join(dst_local_dir_path, src_artifact_dir_path)
    196 inflight_downloads = []
    197 dir_content = [  # prevent infinite loop, sometimes the dir is recursively included
    198     file_info
--> 199     for file_info in self.list_artifacts(src_artifact_dir_path)
    200     if file_info.path != "." and file_info.path != src_artifact_dir_path
    201 ]
    202 if not dir_content:  # empty dir
    203     if not os.path.exists(local_dir):

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/sftp_artifact_repo.py:94, in SFTPArtifactRepository.list_artifacts(self, path)
     92 artifact_dir = self.path
     93 list_dir = posixpath.join(artifact_dir, path) if path else artifact_dir
---> 94 if not self.sftp.isdir(list_dir):
     95     return []
     96 artifact_files = self.sftp.listdir(list_dir)

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py:652, in Connection.isdir(self, remotepath)
    650 self._sftp_connect()
    651 try:
--> 652     result = S_ISDIR(self._sftp.stat(remotepath).st_mode)
    653 except IOError:     # no such file
    654     result = False

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py:493, in SFTPClient.stat(self, path)
    491 path = self._adjust_cwd(path)
    492 self._log(DEBUG, "stat({!r})".format(path))
--> 493 t, msg = self._request(CMD_STAT, path)
    494 if t != CMD_ATTRS:
    495     raise SFTPError("Expected attributes")

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py:822, in SFTPClient._request(self, t, *arg)
    820 def _request(self, t, *arg):
    821     num = self._async_request(type(None), t, *arg)
--> 822     return self._read_response(num)

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py:852, in SFTPClient._read_response(self, waitfor)
    850 while True:
    851     try:
--> 852         t, data = self._read_packet()
    853     except EOFError as e:
    854         raise SSHException("Server connection dropped: {}".format(e))

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py:201, in BaseSFTP._read_packet(self)
    200 def _read_packet(self):
--> 201     x = self._read_all(4)
    202     # most sftp servers won't accept packets larger than about 32k, so
    203     # anything with the high byte set (> 16MB) is just garbage.
    204     if byte_ord(x[0]):

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py:185, in BaseSFTP._read_all(self, n)
    183             break
    184 else:
--> 185     x = self.sock.recv(n)
    187 if len(x) == 0:
    188     raise EOFError()

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py:699, in Channel.recv(self, nbytes)
    686 """
    687 Receive data from the channel.  The return value is a string
    688 representing the data received.  The maximum amount of data to be
   (...)
    696     if no data is ready before the timeout set by `settimeout`.
    697 """
    698 try:
--> 699     out = self.in_buffer.read(nbytes, self.timeout)
    700 except PipeTimeout:
    701     raise socket.timeout()

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/buffered_pipe.py:160, in BufferedPipe.read(self, nbytes, timeout)
    158 while (len(self._buffer) == 0) and not self._closed:
    159     then = time.time()
--> 160     self._cv.wait(timeout)
    161     if timeout is not None:
    162         timeout -= time.time() - then

File ~/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/threading.py:302, in Condition.wait(self, timeout)
    300 try:    # restore state no matter what (e.g., KeyboardInterrupt)
    301     if timeout is None:
--> 302         waiter.acquire()
    303         gotit = True
    304     else:

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

The mlflow tracking server is working properly for all the other operations. I am able to log params, metrics and artifacts. But I am not able to load a model or retrive any of the artifacts.

Update:

Looks like a bug as per https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/5656.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade mlflow, their is some issue with version **1.26.0**

```
pip install mlflow==1.27.0
```

Assuming you are also using above version